# public construction Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor

In activity A, I have this

```
 override fun onTabSelected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                val position = p0?.position
                when (position) {
                    0 ->
                        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                            R.id.frame_container,
                            CallFragment(mWorkOrder.title,mWorkOrder.description,mWorkOrder.location.name,mWorkOrder.status)
                        ).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                }
            }
```

In CallFragment

```
class CallFragment : BaseFragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false)
        return view
    }


    class CallFragment(mTitle: String, mDescription: String, mLocation: String, mStatus: String) {

        var title: String
        var description: String
        var location: String
        var status: String

        init {
            title = mTitle
            description = mDescription
            location = mLocation
            status = mStatus    
        }
    }
```

Error in activity A

```
Too many arguments for public constructor CallFragment() defined in xxx
```

I have defined a new constructor in CallFragment with same number of arguments, but the method seems like not getting called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @ScottHunter The error is my question

Comment: "I have defined a new constructor in CallFragment with same number of arguments" -- no, you have not. You have defined a nested `CallFragment` class. To declare secondary constructors in Kotlin, use the `constructor` keyword, not `class`.

Comment: See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: @CommonsWare I have changed to constructor, but `init` cannot resolved

Comment: And also get `Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead` @ScottHunter

Comment: In general, we don't use custom constructors for fragments. That's the reason for the "Avoid non-default constructors" warning.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there anyway for me to pass the arguments to another class?

Comment: A typical approach is to use `setArguments()` from a factory method (e.g., `newInstance()` implemented on a `companion object`). See the `DetailsFragment` sample in [the `Fragment` JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#Layout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, if you want to pass arguments to a fragment class, the recommended way is using a factory method.

```
class CallFragment : BaseFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false)
        // Get arguments' value
        val title = arguments!!.getString(ARGUMENT_TITLE)
        val description = arguments!!.getString(ARGUMENT_DESCRIPTION)
        val location = arguments!!.getString(ARGUMENT_LOCATION)
        val status = arguments!!.getString(ARGUMENT_STATUS)
        return view
    }

    companion object {
        private const val ARGUMENT_TITLE = "ARGUMENT_TITLE"
        private const val ARGUMENT_DESCRIPTION = "ARGUMENT_DESCRIPTION"
        private const val ARGUMENT_LOCATION = "ARGUMENT_LOCATION"
        private const val ARGUMENT_STATUS = "ARGUMENT_STATUS"

        /**
         * Using this factory method to create an instance of this fragment based on given arguments.
         */
        fun newInstance(title: String, description: String, location: String, status: String): CallFragment {
            return CallFragment().apply {
                val args = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARGUMENT_TITLE, title)
                    putString(ARGUMENT_DESCRIPTION, description)
                    putString(ARGUMENT_LOCATION, location)
                    putString(ARGUMENT_STATUS, status)
                }
                arguments = args
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in activity that using below fragment

```
override fun onTabSelected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                val position = p0?.position
                when (position) {
                    0 ->
                        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                            R.id.frame_container,
                            CallFragment.newInstance(mWorkOrder.title,mWorkOrder.description,mWorkOrder.location.name,mWorkOrder.status)
                        ).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                }
            }
```

Comment: I get error Fragment CallFragment not attached to an activity.

Comment: Glad to hear that.